# Using Polars to remap multiple rows to a columnar representation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, python-polars

I have a sparse data set that I want to convert data in a dataframe from something like:

```
id key value
a  m1  1
a  m2  2
a  m3  1
b  m2  4 
c  m1  2
c  m3  6
d  m4  4
e  m2  1
```

To a more columnar sparse representation like:

```
id    m1    m2    m3    m4
a     1     2     1     NaN
b     NaN   4     Nan   NaN
c     2     NaN   6     NaN
d     NaN   NaN   NaN   4
e     NaN   1     NaN   NaN
```

The rational here is that parts of the processing I am doing relies on the second representation (which is actually much larger and quite sparse).  So it's stored in the first representation and transformed into the second.

In Pandas, a very dumb way of doing this would be something like:

```
a1 = { "id": ["a"], "m1": [1], "m2": [2], "m3": [1] }
a2 = { "id": ["b"], "m2": [4] }
a3 = { "id": ["c"], "m1": [2], "m3": [6] }
a4 = { "id": ["d"], "m4": [4] }
a5 = { "id": ["e"], "m2": [1] }
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=a1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=a2)
d3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=a3)
d4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=a4)
d5 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=a5)
result = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3, d4, d5], ignore_index=True)
print(result)

   id    m1    m2    m3    m4
0   a     1     2     1     NaN
1   b     NaN   4     Nan   NaN
2   c     2     NaN   6     NaN
3   d     NaN   NaN   NaN   4
4   e     NaN   1     NaN   NaN
```

So, as mentioned, I can deconstruct the above result pretty easily.  However, how might one efficiently reconstruct it?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a [*pivot operation*](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/transformations/pivot/), which in polars can be done using [`pl.DataFrame.pivot`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#).

```py
df.pivot(values="value", index="id", columns="key")
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ m1   ┆ m2   ┆ m3   ┆ m4   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ b   ┆ null ┆ 4    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ c   ┆ 2    ┆ null ┆ 6    ┆ null │
│ d   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 4    │
│ e   ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

*Note.* [`pl.DataFrame.pivot`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#) is only available in polars *eager mode*. If you need to use it in *lazy mode*, check out the documentation above. It contains an alternative solution in the case that you know the unique column values in advance.